# Why doesn't this work? (More so Ruby than Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def refresh_menu
    @menu_pages = []

    $menu_items.each do |id|
        @menu_pages[id - 1] = Page.find(id)
    end
end
```

$menu_items is just an array [1,2]. Obviously what I want to do is populate @menu_pages with all the pages found as per $menu_items.

Mind you,

```
@menu_pages = Page.all
```

works just fine. So how come I can't add them one-by-one with Page.find(id)?

The error returned:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Comment: As noted below, this means that $menu_items isn't defined in this context. Beyond that, though, using globals like this in a Rails app is a severe code smell. If I was you I'd try to find a way to do what you're after without using any globals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just do?...

```
def refresh_menu
  @menu_pages = Page.where(:id => $menu_items)
end
```

And in relation to the error, where is `$menu_items` defined?

Answer (score 4):

nowk, thanks for the neat trick.

To those who might find this through search: don't forget to restart the server when you make changes to initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining `$menu_items`? From your error message, it looks like the `refresh_menu` method can't see it - and thus thinks it's `nil`.

Comment: It's defined in initializers/constants.rb so it should be accessible to the controller; and in fact, it is accessible through the rails console.